# Least Significant Bit if there is a binary point

Tags: binary

If I have eight binary positions for instance:

```
  7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
```

its clear what the MSB and LSB is - the Most Significant Bit is the leftmost position (7) and Least Significant Bit the rightmost position (0)

But what if I have a binary.point (that is a fraction speaking decimal) i.e

```
 7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3
```

What could one here say is the most significant bit - is it the bit closest to the binary point or is it at position -3?

*Its regarding floating point numbers*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, in any case it is the "last digit"

From a conceptual point of view, you can just think with decimal numbers :

Which digit is the least interesting, that is the least important if it changes, in :

123.45 $

clearly if i change the 5 i'm changing the "cents"
, which are the least important.

As in 12,345 $ , the least important is still the "5"

Though in 12,345.00 $ , the least important is the last 0.

You're talking about decimal points.

You mean fixed representation ? Or floating point number ?

If it is a fixed representation, then how do you know where is the decimal point ? Is it a convention somewhere ?

because both 123.45 and 12,345 could be, in decimal, represented by "12345". In the first case assuming that we have integers, in the second assuming that we have two-decimal-digits numbers.

If you talk about using floating points, then the notion of "least significant digit" would mean the least siginificant bit of the **mantissa**

but just talking about the "least significant bit" of a sequence of bit, whatever it means, is always the "last" one (or "first" one depending on conventions).

EDIT

For floating point numbers, then you have to remember that it's a complex thing.

I mean complex in the sense that you have several "numbers" packed into the representation in bits.

To take the "usual" 64 floating point (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

you have the first bit for sign, the next 11 are an integer that is the "exponent", and the remaining one are the "mantissa" ("fractional part") (thought as 1.something_meant_by_your_mantissa_bits )

The last (64th) bit is the 52th (last) bit of the mantissa, thus the least significant bit of the corresponding number. But the 12th bit is also a last bit, the last-one of the 11-bit exponent.

I'll try to make again a example with decimal digits (it is a bit simpler and different from the IEEE "double precision")

Let's say we write 8 decimal digits numbers with 5-digits "mantissa" and 3-digits exponent.
in "1.2345 E 678" (meaning 1.2345 times ten to 678)

the "5" is the "least important digit".

If we "pack" the number like the IEEE double, "3digit-exponent then 5digit-mantissa" we would have

> 67812345

so the last digit of the big block is actually the least significant bit of the number.

But if we had another convention of packing, for example if the floating point number is supposed to be "5digit-mantissa then 3digit-exponent"
that is

> 12345678

and in our 8-digit the least significant one is the actually the 5th and not the last (8th) one.
then the least significant digit is not the last one.

It strongly depends on your **convention** of what your numbers (bits) mean.

Usually we talk about least significant bits in Bytes or Words that have meaning like memory address or just rough group of bits. Thus, you can think of them as integer numbers in anyway.

For the convenience, I *guess* the IEEE standard for floating point numbers put the mantissa at the end of the group so that the last bit, that is the least significant bit in the number, corresponds to the usual programming sense of "least significant bit of the group seen as a big pack of bits".

Comment: Ok, I'll add details here in my answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: Thanks again - now i know how to think - using IEEE 754 standard gives a mantissa for 1.2345 => (approx) 00111100000000000000000 i.e 23 bits so in this aspect its more clear in the context of LSB